# Magento 1.9 get watermark images instead of media images

Tags: magento-1.9

Heloo,

I need to get all images from magento 1.9 with watermark:

```
if($show_image != "off"){
    $url_to_image = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product';
    $prod_images = array();
    $prod_images[] = $product->getImage();
    if($has_prod_caracts == false){
        $prod_caracts = enumerateCustomAttributesForProduct($product);
        $has_prod_caracts = false;
    }
    $media_gallery = unserialize($prod_caracts["media_gallery"]);
    $images = $media_gallery['images'];
    foreach($images as $image){
        if($image['file']!=$prod_images[0] && $image['disabled']==0 && $image['disabled_default']==0){
            $prod_images[]=$image['file'];
        }
        if(count($prod_images)>0){
            $prod_image = $url_to_image.implode("||".$url_to_image,$prod_images);
        }     
    }
}
```

the only problem is that this code is for non watremark  images

how do i get only the watermark path.